# Redirect on deny of a confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, redirect

My task is to submit a from based on user confirmation. If the user confirm then the form is submitted. If the user deny then the from is redirected to other page. I've a form in jsp like this -

```
.....
   <form id="stageUpdateForm" method="post">
   </form>
......
```

And in javascript I'm trying -

```
$('#stageUpdateForm').submit(function() {
  decision = confirm("Some data changed. Are you sure?");
  return decision;
  // if user deny then redirect 
});
```

Now if the user deny to submit the from its stay in current page. But I want to redirect the page to other url (eg. - www.google.com) if the user deny. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('#stageUpdateForm').submit(function () {
    var decision = confirm('Some data changed. Are you sure?');

    // if user deny then redirect 
    if (!decision) {
        $(location).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
    }

    // If user confirm, than it will return true and the form will be sumbited
    return decision;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to try something like this:

```
if (decision) {
    window.location = "http://whenever.wherever";
} else {
    // Returning false from a submit handler will prevent the submit action.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If the user confirm then the form is submitted. If the user deny then the from is redirected to other page (eg. - www.google.com).

Comment: OK, flip the code blocks then - the principle applies :)